# MS Excel 2013 function TODAY() not updating unless source file is open

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, matlab

I use the TODAY() function in an excel worksheet which is accessed using MATLAB (i.e. I don't read the worksheet directly). Now I have to open the excel file just to update the TODAY() function, and this method is a bottleneck in my workflow.

I know it's possible to set Excel to automatically update cells upon being opened under the calculation tab, but apparently this does not apply to MATLAB (or COM interfaces in general?). Can someone give me an idea of what can be done?

EDIT: I'm using MATLAB's built in 'xlsread' command

Comment: Excel is working as designed. As you have found out, it does not update any formulas without the file being opened. Therefore, you may have to look for a solution in MATLAB, not Excel. Otherwise, you are left with opening Excel to recalculate the formula.

Comment: Your comment makes complete sense; I was under the wrong impression the excel file operated on its own, but you actually need Excel to calculate all those formulas, not the worksheet itself.

The Matlab forum hasn't been helpful in answering this question

Comment: Could you use `today` or `datestr(datetime('today'))` in Matlab to calculate the date directly? Or maybe `datetime('now','TimeZone','local','Format','dd-MM-yyyy')`

Answer (score 0):

Although it might not be what you expect, It works [according to specs](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Insert-the-current-date-and-time-in-a-cell-02e29e25-93b2-4799-b707-3a9e0ccefd46).

> NOTE: The results of the TODAY and NOW functions change only when the
>   worksheet is calculated or when a macro that contains the function is
>   run. Cells that contain these functions are not updated continuously.

Specifically in your case: note that "the worksheet" references the worksheet where the `TODAY()` formula is located, not the worksheet that references that worksheet.

As for the second part of your question, I think the best way to go is to write a VBA macro, that re-calculates the worksheet. According to [this post](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/100938-how-can-i-run-an-excel-macro-from-matlab?), it should be possible to call an Excel macro from MATLAB (code copied from the linked article):

```
% Create object.
ExcelApp = actxserver('Excel.Application');

% Open file
ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(fullfile(pwd,'\myFile.xls'));

% Run Macro1, defined in "ThisWorkBook" 
ExcelApp.Run('ThisWorkBook.Macro1');
```